# Nomenclature as a chapter

Tags: header-footer, nomenclature

Using `nomencl` I am trying to make a nomenclature at the end of my PhD thesis. But the header of the previous chapter (in this case the appendix) is printed on the second page.

How can I change the header in nomenclature to be NOMENCLATURE instead of the previous chapter?

I don't know if it is relevant but I'm using `book` and creating another index with `makeidx`.

Comment: see also egreg's answer here (I found his solution best):
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133053/nomenclature-header-problems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from the [`nomencl`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl) package documentation (page 9)

> If you are using e. g. the documentclass book with page style headings
>   you should also take care of correct headings:
>
> ```
> \cleardoublepage% or \clearpage
>    \markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}% maybe with \MakeUppercase
>    \printnomenclature
> ```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does, thx.