# Nomenclature header problems

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, nomenclature

I'm writing a document in book class, using the `fancyhdr` package. I have both an index, and a symbol list, for which I use the `imakeidx` and `nomencl` packages.
I had problems with getting the right headers for both. I managed to set the index straight, by using `\indexsetup{level=\chapter}` (which works fine since `\backmatter` had already been declared).
However, I couldn't find out how do to the same for the nomenclature, so I ended up manually calling `\markboth` directly after `\printnomenclature`. This works, but feels dodgy (e.g., if I switched the order of the two, the `\markboth` affected the last chapter).

I was hoping someone had a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `\printnomenclature` command after `\backmatter`, it's simple:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
```

In this way, the `thenomenclature` package will issue `\chapter{\nomname}` and the entry will set the headings and the annotation for the table of contents. Don't add the `intoc` option to `nomencl`.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks