# Make nomenclature as a subsection of a chapter

Tags: sections-paragraphs, nomenclature, nomencl

I am writing my Phd Thesis. For a chapter, I want as a first section the introduction and as a second the Nomenclature.
When I use the `\printnomenclature`, there are two clear pages skipped before starting the nomenclature. How can I make the nomenclature as a section and just after the end of my introduction (without clear pages)?

Comment: What package are you using for `\printnomenclature`? Please provide a MVE. It probably uses `\chapter` or `\chapter*` internally. A hack would be to redefine `\chapter*` temporarily.

Comment: This may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133054/142180

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @OlegLobachev: In fact, the linked answer to the patch is the better way to go...

Comment: Yep, the `\chapter*` hack was the first guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `nomencl` package defines `\printnomenclature` like

```
% nomencl.sty, line 156:
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
  {
    \section*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  {
    \chapter*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%

  \nompreamble
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
```

What you want is to redefine it in your document preamble as

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thenomenclature{%
  \section*{\nomname}%
  \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi
  \nompreamble
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother
```