# Nomencl with nomentbl option and custom chapter in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, nomencl

I'm trying to use the `nomentbl` option with the `nomencl` package and at the same time add a numbered chapter to the TOC, where I have a custom name for the nomenclature chapter title.

I get the custom chapter part to work if I'm not trying to use the `nomentbl` option, but with it, it fails. The output shows errors such as:

```
l.4   \item &
         {a}&\begingroup acceleration\endgroup &\begingroup \meter/\seco...
./test.nls:4: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

The redefining of `thenomenclature` I've taken from other questions (like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408398/make-nomenclature-as-a-subsection-of-a-chapter)) and I'm guessing the problem for me lies here, but I don't know how to adapt it to my needs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
\@ifundefined{chapter}%
{
    \section{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
}%
{
    \chapter{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
}%

\nompreamble
\list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\nomenclature{COM}{Commissioning}{}{}%
\nomenclature{a}{acceleration}{\meter/\second\squared}{}%

\renewcommand{\nomname}{My title for definitions}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in the following example seems to fix it. Taken from the documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nomentbl]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
\@ifundefined{chapter}%
{
    \section{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
}%
{
    \chapter{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
}%

\nompreamble
\let\itemOrig=\item
\def\item{\gdef\item{\\}}%
\expandafter\longtable\expandafter{\@nomtableformat}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\nomenclature{COM}{Commissioning}{}{}%
\nomenclature{a}{acceleration}{\meter/\second\squared}{}%

\renewcommand{\nomname}{My title for definitions}
\printnomenclature%

\end{document}
```