# Nomenclature Header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, titles, nomenclature, appendix

I'm printing the Nomenclature of my document after my appendix.
However, the header of my Nomenclature shows the title of my last appendix and I can't figure out why.

This is a sample of my main document :

```
\appendix

\chapter{Material Properties}
\input{Appendix/MaterialProperties.tex}

\chapter{List of Components}
\input{Appendix/ListComponents.tex}

\chapter{Technical Drawings}
\input{Appendix/TechnicalDrawings.tex}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature\newpage
```

[image: Here you can see what happens]

I thought about adding it as a chapter but it either messes out the title of the nomenclature (it shows up twice, or with more blank space), or messes up my table of contents!

If you have any advice, I would be really grateful! 
Thank you :)

Comment: see heading issues here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31586/nomenclature-as-a-chapter if your getting duplicate entries see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32891/nomenclature-duplicates

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?